# Oracle - sys_connect_by_path functionality

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have below input data in table

```
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
device_count| dmc_id| firmware_version| charging_group_id|image_prerequisite| count_within_dmcid|
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
| 5         | 3345  |SU.B             |0000000000000000 |SU.A              | 93                |
| 6         | 3345  |SU.C             |0000000000000000 |SU.B              | 93                |
| 8         | 3345  |SU.D             |0000000000000000 |SU.C              | 93                |
| 8         | 3345  |SU.E             |0000000000000000 |SU.C              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.F             |0000000000000000 |SU.D              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.F             |0000000000000000 |SU.E              | 93                |
| 10        | 3345  |SU.G             |0000000000000000 |SU.F              | 93                |
| 11        | 3345  |SU.H             |0000000000000000 |SU.F              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.I             |0000000000000000 |SU.G              | 93                |
| 20        | 3345  |SU.I             |0000000000000000 |SU.H              | 93                |
| 5         | 3345  |SU.A             |0000000000000000 |null              | 93                |
| 40        | 408   |RT2              |0000000000000000 |RT1               | 24028             |
| 24        | 408   |RT3              |0000000000000000 |RT2               | 24028             |
| 18        | 408   |RT4              |0000000000000000 |RT3               | 24028             |
| 2109      | 408   |RT1              |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 1422  |RT1              |0000000000000000 |null              | 7                 |
| 1         | 1422  |RT2              |0000000000000000 |RT1               | 7                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000041 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000334 |null              | 2                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000359 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000000441 |null              | 1                 |
| 1         | 408   |RT1              |HFOTA-0000001885 |null              | 2                 |
| 4         | 408   |SVP01            |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 11        | 408   |Sanity01         |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |Sanity1          |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 6         | 408   |TB_HT01          |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 1         | 408   |TEST_1           |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 5         | 408   |TK_ST001         |0000000000000000 |null              | 24028             |
| 2         | 3345  |FW.D             |0000000000000000 |FW.C              | 24028             |
| 8         | 3345  |FW.E             |0000000000000000 |FW.D              | 24028             |
| 4         | 3345  |FW.F             |0000000000000000 |FW.E              | 24028             |
+-----------+-------+-----------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

I am using below query to create chain of firmware_version and finding cumulative count.

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT device_count,
    dmc_id,
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(image_prerequisite) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite) > 1
      THEN 
      MIN(firmware_version) 
      --WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY firmware_version) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite) || '+N'
      ELSE firmware_version
    END firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  FROM dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw
  ),
  t2 AS
  (SELECT SUM(device_count) device_count,
    dmc_id,
    firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY dmc_id,
    firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  ),
  t3 AS
  (SELECT t.*,
    LEVEL lev,
    sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/') AS chain,
    connect_by_root(firmware_version) root_fw,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, firmware_version, connect_by_root(firmware_version) ORDER BY LEVEL DESC, sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/')) rn
  FROM t2 t
    START WITH image_prerequisite                                    IS NULL
    CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR regexp_substr(firmware_version, '[^+]*') = image_prerequisite
  AND PRIOR dmc_id                                                    = dmc_id
  AND PRIOR charging_group_id                                         = charging_group_id
  )
SELECT chain,
  root_fw,
  firmware_version AS fw,
  device_count     AS cnt,
  dmc_id,
  charging_group_id,
  count_within_dmcid,
  SUM(device_count) over(PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, root_fw ORDER BY lev DESC) AS cumm,
  lev,
  rn
FROM t3
ORDER BY dmc_id,
  charging_group_id,
  lev DESC;
```

Results Query is returning: It is not returning the chain for firmware_versions FW.D, FW.E, FW.F because we are using START WITH image_prerequisite                                  IS NULL. 
Please suggest a way we can address the chain of firmware which does not have the starting point (Image Prerequisite) as NULL.

```
CHAIN                                         ROOT_FW    FW                     CNT     DMC_ID CG_ID            LEV        COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID         RN       CUMM
--------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ------------------ ---------- ----------
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4                              RT1        RT4                     18        408 0000000000000000  4              24028          1         18
/RT1/RT2/RT3                                  RT1        RT3                     24        408 0000000000000000  3              24028          1         42
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                     40        408 0000000000000000  2              24028          1         82
/SVP01                                        SVP01      SVP01                    4        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          4
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                   2109        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1       2191
/Sanity01                                     Sanity01   Sanity01                11        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1         11
/Sanity1                                      Sanity1    Sanity1                  1        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          1
/TB_HT01                                      TB_HT01    TB_HT01                  6        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          6
/TEST_1                                       TEST_1     TEST_1                   1        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          1
/TK_ST001                                     TK_ST001   TK_ST001                 5        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          5
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000041  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000334  1                  2          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000359  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000441  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000001885  1                  2          1          1
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                      1       1422 0000000000000000  2                  7          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1       1422 0000000000000000  1                  7          1          2
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N/SU.I       SU.A       SU.I                    20       3345 0000000000000000  7                 93          1         20
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N            SU.A       SU.G+N                  21       3345 0000000000000000  6                 93          1         41
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F                   SU.A       SU.F                    20       3345 0000000000000000  5                 93          1         61
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N                        SU.A       SU.D+N                  16       3345 0000000000000000  4                 93          1         77
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C                               SU.A       SU.C                     6       3345 0000000000000000  3                 93          1         83
/SU.A/SU.B                                    SU.A       SU.B                     5       3345 0000000000000000  2                 93          1         88
/SU.A                                         SU.A       SU.A                     5       3345 0000000000000000  1                 93          1         93
```

Expected output:

```
CHAIN                                         ROOT_FW    FW                     CNT     DMC_ID CG_ID            LEV        COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID         RN       CUMM
--------------------------------------------- ---------- --------------- ---------- ---------- ---------------- ---------- ------------------ ---------- ----------
/RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4                              RT1        RT4                     18        408 0000000000000000  4              24028          1         18
/RT1/RT2/RT3                                  RT1        RT3                     24        408 0000000000000000  3              24028          1         42
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                     40        408 0000000000000000  2              24028          1         82
/SVP01                                        SVP01      SVP01                    4        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          4
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                   2109        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1       2191
/Sanity01                                     Sanity01   Sanity01                11        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1         11
/Sanity1                                      Sanity1    Sanity1                  1        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          1
/TB_HT01                                      TB_HT01    TB_HT01                  6        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          6
/TEST_1                                       TEST_1     TEST_1                   1        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          1
/TK_ST001                                     TK_ST001   TK_ST001                 5        408 0000000000000000  1              24028          1          5
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000041  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000334  1                  2          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000359  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000000441  1                  1          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1        408 HFOTA-0000001885  1                  2          1          1
/RT1/RT2                                      RT1        RT2                      1       1422 0000000000000000  2                  7          1          1
/RT1                                          RT1        RT1                      1       1422 0000000000000000  1                  7          1          2
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N/SU.I       SU.A       SU.I                    20       3345 0000000000000000  7                 93          1         20
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N            SU.A       SU.G+N                  21       3345 0000000000000000  6                 93          1         41
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F                   SU.A       SU.F                    20       3345 0000000000000000  5                 93          1         61
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N                        SU.A       SU.D+N                  16       3345 0000000000000000  4                 93          1         77
/SU.A/SU.B/SU.C                               SU.A       SU.C                     6       3345 0000000000000000  3                 93          1         83
/SU.A/SU.B                                    SU.A       SU.B                     5       3345 0000000000000000  2                 93          1         88
/SU.A                                         SU.A       SU.A                     5       3345 0000000000000000  1                 93          1         93
/FW.D/FW.E/FW.F                               FW.D       FW.F                     4       3345 0000000000000000  3                 93          1          4
/FW.D/FW.E                                    FW.D       FW.E                     8       3345 0000000000000000  2                 93          1         12
/FW.D                                         FW.D       FW.D                     2       3345 0000000000000000  1                 93          1         14
```

Comment: @Boneist Please suggest a way to handle above scenario

Comment: How do you know that `FW.D` is a beginning of the chain ? A row with `firmware_version=FW.D` has `FW.C` in `image_prerequisite` column. I can't find `FW.C` value elsewhere.

Comment: That is the reason this query is not picking up this chain because we don't have FW.C in the input data .. in previous scenarios we had entry point of chain with prerequisite as NULL value.

Comment: So modify the `START WITH ` clause, just: `START WITH image_prerequisite  IS NULL     OR image_prerequisite NOT IN ( SELECT firmware_version FROM dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw )`. This will include all record for which a value of `image_prerequisite` does not exists in the table.

Comment: The query references `CHARGING_GROUP_ID` column, but there is no such a column in your sample data. It is hard to test your query in SQLFilddle or elsewhere because your query doesn't even compiles. I vote to close your question, because it's impossible to reproduce this problem basing on information you provide in the question.

Comment: @krokodilko I have updated my input data column - cg_id was actually charging_group_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment, if you modify the `START WITH` clause in this way:

```
START WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
      OR image_prerequisite NOT IN ( 
          SELECT firmware_version FROM dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw
    )
```

then `FWD` will be included as a beginning of the chain.
This query: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e4e13/3

gives the following results:

```
WITH t1 AS
  (SELECT device_count,
    dmc_id,
    CASE
      WHEN COUNT(image_prerequisite) OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite) > 1
      THEN 
      MIN(firmware_version) 
      --WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY firmware_version) 
      OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, image_prerequisite) || '+N'
      ELSE firmware_version
    END firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  FROM dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw
  ),
  t2 AS
  (SELECT SUM(device_count) device_count,
    dmc_id,
    firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  FROM t1
  GROUP BY dmc_id,
    firmware_version,
    charging_group_id,
    image_prerequisite,
    count_within_dmcid
  ),
  t3 AS
  (SELECT t.*,
    LEVEL lev,
    sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/') AS chain,
    connect_by_root(firmware_version) root_fw,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, firmware_version, connect_by_root(firmware_version) ORDER BY LEVEL DESC, sys_connect_by_path(firmware_version, '/')) rn
  FROM t2 t
    START WITH image_prerequisite IS NULL
          OR image_prerequisite NOT IN ( 
              SELECT firmware_version FROM dm_temp_summing_dvc_by_fw
        )
    CONNECT BY nocycle PRIOR regexp_substr(firmware_version, '[^+]*') = image_prerequisite
  AND PRIOR dmc_id                                                    = dmc_id
  AND PRIOR charging_group_id                                         = charging_group_id
  )
SELECT chain,
  root_fw,
  firmware_version AS fw,
  device_count     AS cnt,
  dmc_id,
  charging_group_id,
  count_within_dmcid,
  SUM(device_count) over(PARTITION BY dmc_id, charging_group_id, root_fw ORDER BY lev DESC) AS cumm,
  lev,
  rn
FROM t3
ORDER BY 1;
```

---

```
|                                   CHAIN |  ROOT_FW |       FW |  CNT | DMC_ID | CHARGING_GROUP_ID | COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID | CUMM | LEV | RN |
|-----------------------------------------|----------|----------|------|--------|-------------------|--------------------|------|-----|----|
|                                   /FW.D |     FW.D |     FW.D |    2 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   14 |   1 |  1 |
|                              /FW.D/FW.E |     FW.D |     FW.E |    8 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   12 |   2 |  1 |
|                         /FW.D/FW.E/FW.F |     FW.D |     FW.F |    4 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    4 |   3 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 | 2109 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 | 2191 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |   1422 |  0000000000000000 |                  7 |    2 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |    408 |  HFOTA-0000000041 |                  1 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |    408 |  HFOTA-0000000334 |                  2 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |    408 |  HFOTA-0000001885 |                  2 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |    408 |  HFOTA-0000000441 |                  1 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                    /RT1 |      RT1 |      RT1 |    1 |    408 |  HFOTA-0000000359 |                  1 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                /RT1/RT2 |      RT1 |      RT2 |    1 |   1422 |  0000000000000000 |                  7 |    1 |   2 |  1 |
|                                /RT1/RT2 |      RT1 |      RT2 |   40 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   82 |   2 |  1 |
|                            /RT1/RT2/RT3 |      RT1 |      RT3 |   24 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   42 |   3 |  1 |
|                        /RT1/RT2/RT3/RT4 |      RT1 |      RT4 |   18 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   18 |   4 |  1 |
|                                   /SU.A |     SU.A |     SU.A |    5 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   93 |   1 |  1 |
|                              /SU.A/SU.B |     SU.A |     SU.B |    5 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   88 |   2 |  1 |
|                         /SU.A/SU.B/SU.C |     SU.A |     SU.C |    6 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   83 |   3 |  1 |
|                  /SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N |     SU.A |   SU.D+N |   16 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   77 |   4 |  1 |
|             /SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F |     SU.A |     SU.F |   20 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   61 |   5 |  1 |
|      /SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N |     SU.A |   SU.G+N |   21 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   41 |   6 |  1 |
| /SU.A/SU.B/SU.C/SU.D+N/SU.F/SU.G+N/SU.I |     SU.A |     SU.I |   20 |   3345 |  0000000000000000 |                 93 |   20 |   7 |  1 |
|                                  /SVP01 |    SVP01 |    SVP01 |    4 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    4 |   1 |  1 |
|                               /Sanity01 | Sanity01 | Sanity01 |   11 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |   11 |   1 |  1 |
|                                /Sanity1 |  Sanity1 |  Sanity1 |    1 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                                /TB_HT01 |  TB_HT01 |  TB_HT01 |    6 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    6 |   1 |  1 |
|                                 /TEST_1 |   TEST_1 |   TEST_1 |    1 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    1 |   1 |  1 |
|                               /TK_ST001 | TK_ST001 | TK_ST001 |    5 |    408 |  0000000000000000 |              24028 |    5 |   1 |  1 |
```

The only differences from your expected output are values in `COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID` column, I really don't get how they are calculated.

Comment: Thank you ! COUNT_WITHIN_DMCID is the value that we are getting in input data itself.